# Select pandas columns by several strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have tried to select several rows of dataframe by specific partial string.

The dataframe below is the original example data:

```
CODE        DATA 
AA2016      47518  
BB2016      47518  
CC2014      47518  
AA2014      47518  
EE2015      47518  
BB2015      47518  
FF2016      47518  
AA2013      47518
```

I want to select the rows by the first two words in `Code` Column.

For example, I want to choose the rows containing "AA","BB","CC" in the "Code" column.

The result should represent like this:

[image]

I use the code like this:

```
Select_list = ["AA","BB", "CC"]

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df1 = df[df.CODE.str[0:2] isin Select_list]
```

But there would be error appear like `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: It should be `df1 = df[df.CODE.str[0:2].isin(Select_list)]`

Answer (score 1):

As @ayhan notes in the comment, you can use `df[df.CODE.str[0:2].isin(Select_list)]`.

Alternatively, note that you can use regular expressions via [`pd.Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame({'CODE': ['AA2016', 'BB2015', 'AB2015']})

In [7]: df.CODE.str.contains(r'AA.*|BB.*|CC.*')
Out[7]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: CODE, dtype: bool
```

(For this specific pattern, though, the slicing is probably simpler.)